# example of two groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Are there two infinite and non- abelian finitely generated groups $G$ and $H$ such that $\frac{G}{ G^{\prime}} \cong \frac{H}{H^{\prime}}$ and $G^{\prime}$ is finite but $H^{\prime}$ is infinite?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic in its current form, because an easy counter-example has been provided

Comment: thanks, I would like to know with what extra condition, we have $G^{\prime}\cong H^{\prime}$?

Comment: @agoal As the example I gave shows, I think it would be rather difficult to get that kind of condition out of anything that is reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to put more conditions. Otherwise, take $G=\mathbb{Z}^2\times S$ where $S$ is a nonabelian finite simple group, and $H=F(x,y)$, the free group of rank $2$. Then $G/G' \cong H/H' \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$, $G'\cong S$, and $H'$ is free of countable rank.